# Javascript get value from multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I experience an issue with getting values from an array. For some reason I can't get it to work (just getting [object]) and appreciate any help here:

Here I'm creating the response

```
    foreach ($locations as $location) {
        if($location->getStreet1() != ''){
            $result .= $location->getStreet1() .', ';
        }
        if($location->getCity() != ''){
            $result .= $location->getCity() .', ';
        }
        $locationList[$i]['location'] = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($location->getName()));
        $locationList[$i]['address'] = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($result));
        $i++;
        $result = '';
    }
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array('locations' => $locationList)));
```

And here I'm handling the response:

```
                        request.done(function(data) {

                            var container = jQuery('#hotel-list-container');
                            var locations = jQuery.parseJSON(data).locations;

                            container.html('');
                            var firstSymbols = [];

                            locations.forEach(function(location) {
                                var firstSymbol = location.location;

                                if (jQuery.inArray(firstSymbol, firstSymbols) === -1) {
                                    firstSymbols.push(firstSymbol);
                                }
                            });

                            firstSymbols.forEach(function(firstSymbol) {
                                if (jQuery.isNumeric(firstSymbol)) {
                                    if (container.find('.numeric').size() === 0) {
                                        container.append('<div class="numeric">0&ndash;9</div>');
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    container.append('<div class="letter">' + firstSymbol + '</div>');
                                }

                                locations.forEach(function(data) {
                                    if (firstSymbol == data.location) {
                                        container.append('<div class="hotel-item"><a class="hotel" data-id="' + data.location + '"><div class="hotel_addr_div"><span>' + data.location +'</span>'+data.address+'</div></a></div>');
                                        console.log(data.location);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                            container.slideDown(null, function() {
                                jQuery('#hotel-list-container').mCustomScrollbar({ scrollInertia: 0 });
                            });
                        });


locations.forEach(function(data) {
    if (firstSymbol == data.location) {
        container.append('<div class="hotel-item">
            <a class="hotel" data-id="' + data.location + '">
                <div class="hotel_div"><span>' + data.location +'</span>'+data.address+'</div>
            </a>
        </div>');
                                     }
```

And that is what I'm seeing in frontend

```
<div class="hotel-lists" id="hotel-list-container-mobile" style="max-height: 497px;">
    <div class="letter">undefined</div>
    <div class="hotel-item"><a class="hotel" data-id="[object Object]">[object Object]</a></div>
    <div class="hotel-item"><a class="hotel" data-id="[object Object]">[object Object]</a></div>
    <div class="hotel-item"><a class="hotel" data-id="[object Object]">[object Object]</a></div>
</div>
```

**Thanks for all answers. Like requested I added the full code in here**

Comment: Your javascript code looks inconsistent with frontend: javascript defines class as `hotel`, but the frontend says class is `hotel-item`.

Comment: No, the `hotel` is the inner `a` tag.

Comment: please add some data from `data`.

Comment: can you do a `console.log(locations)`?

Comment: The JS code and the HTML do not match (different container id, different format for links). Please make sure you provide consistent data.